# Error: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property

Tags: c#, winforms, button

```
if (pattern[x] == 0)
                {
                    Form1.button0.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                }
                else if (pattern[x] == 1)
                {

                }
                else if (pattern[x] == 2)
                {

                }
                else
                {

                }
```

I'm trying to set the button backcolor, but whenever I try it doesn't recognise that button0 is a thing :/

Comment: Change `Form1` to `this`.

Comment: `Form1` is the class, not an instance of that class. You need an instance of `Form1` to access `button0`

Comment: Form1 is a class.  you need to use an instance of that class, i.e. a variable of type Form1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `Form1` so something like this:

```
var myForm = new Form1();
if (pattern[x] == 0)
{
    myForm.button0.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
else if (pattern[x] == 1)
{
    //...
}
else if (pattern[x] == 2)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

**NOTE:** `ShowDialog()` at the end will actually show your form as a dialog. You could just use `.Show()` but it depends on how you want to display the form. This should get your started though!

Answer (score 0):

If indeed `button0` exists in your `Form1` (it is created in your Form1.desginer.cs)
you can simply access it by:

```
button0.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```